# Kindly explain me the reason for usage of a comma in this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

In this sentence "They waste their time, thinking that they would make up the loss in future."  kindly explain me the reason for usage of a comma before the word THINKING.

Comment: There's no grammatical need, but this might be used to suggest place for the speaker to pause slightly.

Comment: It helps to clarify that they waste their time and they think they will make up the loss, instead of the less likely meaning that they are occupying the wasted time with thoughts of making up the loss.

Comment: What @Peter said. Without the comma, it's at least *possible* to parse adverbial ***thinking** [blah blah]* as applying solely to the preceding verb - *to **waste** [time]* (i.e. - the adverbial element specifies ***how*** the time was wasted, by using it to have those thoughts). As opposed to ***with*** the comma, which introduces enough separation between the two clauses that we naturally see what follows the comma as a "**sentence adverb**" - effectively specifying ***why*** the time was wasted, not ***how***..

Answer (score 4):

Agreeing with @Peter

> "They waste their time thinking that they would make up the loss in
> future."

This could be construed to mean, they waste their time by spending it *thinking*. In other words they are sitting around actively "thinking that they would make up for the loss". That would be a big waste of time.

> "They waste their time, thinking that they would make up the loss in
> future."

This means that, because they believe that they can make up the loss later, they are wasting their time by playing cards/drinking/talking about inconsequential matters etc.  instead of trying to make up the loss now or at least planning for it.